# How to get the function that shows the relationship between wage and labor supplied

Tags: microeconomics, labor-economics

In the purchase-leisure trade-off curve, we get the relationship between wage and working hours. But how can we get the relationship between wage and quantity of labor supplied? The demand curve is easy to get, the firms basically stop hiring workers when the wage exceeds the MRPL. But without the supply curve, the wage in the perfectly competitive input market will be hard to get.

Answer (score 1):

Number of working hours **is** the quantity of labor supplied. If you don’t like to measure labor supply in working hours but different metric all you need to do is convert the working hours to desired metric.